# Displaying collection issue

Tags: playframework

I have an Entity called `Album` which has a `@ManyToOne` relationship to `Author`.

Well, I am trying to display the name of the author in my html file like this:

```
Author is: #{a @SermonsIndex.sermonsByAuthor(albums.author.name)}${albums.author.name}#{/a}
```

For some reason it prints the name like: `[Elvis]` so it appends '[' and ']' instead of showing it clean.(`Elvis`)

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for such a basic question. Of course, being a collection I should use an index to get it, eg:

`Author is: #{a @SermonsIndex.sermonsByAuthor(albums[0].author.name)}${albums[0].author.name}#{/a}`